# Desktop Launcher for Python Script Starts Program in Wrong Path

Tags: python, linux, filepath, launcher, linux-mint

I can not launch a python script from a .desktop launcher created on Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon.

The problem is that the script will be launched in the wrong path - namely the *home folder* instead of the directory it is placed in. Thereby it can not find other vital files accompanying it in its folder and hence does not work.

To examine that misbehaviour I created a short script to check the folder a python script is executing in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time

subprocess.call(["pwd"], shell=True)
time.sleep(7)  # to get a chance to read the output
```

Executing it from its own folder gives the output:

```
/home/myusername/PythonProjects
```

I am setting a desktop launcher via Nemo's menu. Now executing the same script yields:

```
/home/myusername
```

**I do not understand this behaviour. How could I create a working desktop launcher for  my python script?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [page](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) describes the format of `.desktop` files.

You may note the "Path" element, which specifies the working directory for the file to be run in. In your case you would want a desktop file that specified

```
Path=/home/myusername/PythonProjects
```

If Nemo doesn't allow you to set the Path element you may need to edit the desktop file by hand. The .desktop files are text files and you can probably find them in `/home/myusername/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, James. While adding the Path entry to the desktop file of the described text program indeed changed the working directory, my actual program still can not be run this way. Instead it start is aborted with the error message: "There was an error launching the application." How to proceed from here? What information would your require to understand my problem?

Comment: Glad to help somewhat. The error would be a different issue. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/436999/how-do-i-diagnose-there-was-an-error-launching-the-application for a procedure for diagnosing what the error actually is

Comment: Dear, James thank you for your valuable input. I succeeded in working around the error I described by placing a shell script with the sole command of starting my python script within the respective folder. I was then able to launch that shell script and hence my python app via a .desktop launcher. Yet, the .desktop fie had to be extended by stating the working directory in the way you suggested. I am very satisfied with the result and feel I have deepened my understanding of Linux. Yet, I do not understand why a launcher would not by default start its target within it its own directory.